# R list.files: some regexes only return a single file

Tags: r, regex

I'm puzzled by the behaviour of regexes in the list.files command. I have a folder with ~500 files, most names start with "new_" and end with ".txt". There are some other files on the same folder, e.g. README, _cabs.txt.

I'd like to get *only* the new_*.txt files. I've tried different ways to call list.files with different results. Here are they:

```
#1 This returns ALL files including README and others
list.files(path="correctpath/") 
#2 This returns ALL files including _cabs.txt, which I do not want.
list.files(path="correctpath/",pattern="txt")
#3 This returns ALL files I want, but...
list.files(path="correctpath/",pattern="new_")
#4 This returns just one of the new_*.txt files.  
list.files(path="correctpath/",pattern="new*\\.txt")
#5 This returns an empty list.
list.files(path="correctpath/",pattern="new_*\\.txt")
```

So I have one solution that works, but would like to understand what's going on with the approaches 4 and 5.

thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: You need to escape actually since `*` is a special character. So something like `new_\\*.*txt` or if there's no ambiguity just `new_.*txt`. Can't  test, can't create new files.

Answer (score 4):

```
list.files(path="correctpath/",pattern="new_.*\\.txt")
```

`*` means 0 or more times. If you want to match any character 0 or more time you need to add a period before it `.*` because a period means any character (except newline). The pattern `"new_.*\\.txt"` should work.

[Good R regex reference](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! Would still like to understand why there was only one file listed when running list.files(path="correctpath/",pattern="new*\\.txt")

Comment: @RafaelSantos Because you probably have a file named `new.txt` and the metacharacter `*` is matching *the previous character **zero** or more **times***.